# Can Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c) ever throw ClassCastException if c is not null?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, standard-library

The javadoc for `Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)` from the package `java.util` in the standard library for Java 20 [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T%5B%5D,java.util.Comparator)) reads as follows:

> public static  void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
> Sorts the specified array of objects according to the order induced by the specified comparator. **All elements in the array must be mutually comparable by the specified comparator (that is, c.compare(e1, e2) must not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the array)**.
>
> This sort is guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort.
>
> Implementation note: This implementation is a stable, adaptive, iterative mergesort that requires far fewer than n lg(n) comparisons when the input array is partially sorted, while offering the performance of a traditional mergesort when the input array is randomly ordered. If the input array is nearly sorted, the implementation requires approximately n comparisons. Temporary storage requirements vary from a small constant for nearly sorted input arrays to n/2 object references for randomly ordered input arrays.
>
> The implementation takes equal advantage of ascending and descending order in its input array, and can take advantage of ascending and descending order in different parts of the same input array. It is well-suited to merging two or more sorted arrays: simply concatenate the arrays and sort the resulting array.
>
> The implementation was adapted from Tim Peters's list sort for Python ( TimSort). It uses techniques from Peter McIlroy's "Optimistic Sorting and Information Theoretic Complexity", in Proceedings of the Fourth Annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms, pp 467-474, January 1993.
>
> Type Parameters:
> T - the class of the objects to be sorted
> Parameters:
> a - the array to be sorted
> c - the comparator to determine the order of the array. A null value indicates that the elements' natural ordering should be used.
> Throws:
> **ClassCastException - if the array contains elements that are not mutually comparable using the specified comparator**
> IllegalArgumentException - (optional) if the comparator is found to violate the Comparator contract

Emphasis mine.

Doesn't the compiler guarantee (through the use of the type system and the generic signature of the method) that all elements of `a` are in fact mutually comparable using `c` and that `c.compare(e1, e2)` will never throw `ClassCastException`, provided `c` is not null?

Presumably, the "actual" signature of `toArray`, with the type parameters erased, would look like so: `static void sort(Object[] a, Comparator c)` and the signature of `c.compare` (let's assume `c` has the static type `Number` in our program) would look like so: `int compare(Object o1, Object  o2)` and would contain two casts to `Number` in its implementation:

```
Number e1 = (Number) o1;
Number e2 = (Number) o2;
//...
```

These casts succeed if and only if the runtime type of `o1` and `o2` is either `Number` or a sub-type of `Number`.

The runtime type of `o1` and `o2` is either `Number` or a sub-type of `Number` if and only if the runtime type of `a` is either `Number[]` or a sub-type of `Number[]`, e.g. `Integer[]`.

The runtime type of `a` is either `Number[]` or a sub-type of `Number[]` if and only if the static type of `a` is either `Number[]` or a sub-type of `Number[]`. (if the runtime type of `a` is *not* `Number[]` or a sub-type of `Number[]` but the static type of `a` is, a `ClassCastException` will be thrown *before* the body of `Arrays.sort` is entered)

That the static type of `a` is either `Number[]` or a sub-type of `Number[]` follows from the method signature `static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)` because the static type of `c` is `Number` (`? super T` is `Number` so `T` is either `Number` or a sub-type of `Number`).

I've written some tests to try and get `Arrays.sort` to throw a `ClassCastException`, and only really got it when passing `null` for `c` instead of an actual comparator.

```
package org.example.basics.generics.arrays;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

class ArraysTest {

    private static final Comparator<Number> compareAsWholeNumber = new Comparator<Number>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(java.lang.Number o1, java.lang.Number o2) {
            return Long.compare(o1.longValue(), o2.longValue());
        }
    };

    @Test
    public void sortingIntsThrowsNoException() {
        Integer[] ints = new Integer[]{4, 2, 3};
        Assertions.assertDoesNotThrow(() -> {
            Arrays.sort(ints, compareAsWholeNumber);
        });

    }

    @Test
    public void sortingDoublesThrowsNoException() {
        Double[] doubles = new Double[]{4.0, 2.0, 3.0};
        Assertions.assertDoesNotThrow(() -> {
            Arrays.sort(doubles, compareAsWholeNumber);
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void sortingNumbersThrowsNoException() {
        Number[] numbers = new Number[]{4.0, 2, 3.0f};
        Assertions.assertDoesNotThrow(() -> {
            Arrays.sort(numbers, compareAsWholeNumber);
        });
    }

//    @Test
//    public void sortingObjectsIsCompileError() {
//        Object[] numbers = new Number[]{4.0, 2, 3.0f};
//        Arrays.sort(numbers, compareAsWholeNumber);
//    }

    @Test
    public void sortingDisguisedStringsThrowsClassCastException() {
        Throwable e = Assertions.assertThrows(ClassCastException.class, () -> {
            Arrays.sort((Number[]) new Object[]{"4.0", "2", "3.0f"}, compareAsWholeNumber);
        });
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Test
    public void sortingDisguisedStringsThrowsClassCastExceptionAtArrayAssignment() {
        Assertions.assertThrows(ClassCastException.class, () -> {
            Number[] numbers = (Number[]) new Object[]{"4.0", "2", "3.0f"};
        });
    }
    @Test
    public void sortingNonComparableWithNullComparatorThrowsClassCastException() {
        Number[] numbers = new Number[]{4.0, 2, 3.0f};
        Throwable e = Assertions.assertThrows(ClassCastException.class, () -> {
            Arrays.sort(numbers, null);
        });
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The above test suite runs successfully on my machine using Eclipse Temurin 20.0.2.

Note especially the last 4 tests.

`sortingObjectsIsCompileError`: Passing an array with a static type that is neither `Number[]` nor a sub-type of `Number[]` to `sort` is a compile error.
Uncommenting that test and trying to compile produces the following for me:

> TestToArray.java:46: error: no suitable method found for sort(Object[],Comparator)
> Arrays.sort(numbers, compareAsWholeNumber);
> ^
> method Arrays.<T#1>sort(T#1[],Comparator<? super T#1>) is not applicable
> (inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
> upper bounds: Number,Object
> lower bounds: Object)
> method Arrays.<T#2>sort(T#2[],int,int,Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
> (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
> (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
> where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
> T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>sort(T#1[],Comparator<? super T#1>)
> T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(T#2[],int,int,Comparator<? super T#2>)

`sortingDisguisedStringsThrowsClassCastException`: As the name suggests, a `ClassCastException` is indeed thrown here, but this is misleading: Printing the stacktrace to std_out yields the following (reduced for brevity):

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Number; ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [Ljava.lang.Number; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
> at org.example.basics.generics.arrays.TestToArray.lambda$sortingDisguisedStringsThrowsClassCastException$3(TestToArray.java:52) <3 internal lines>
> at org.example.basics.generics.arrays.TestToArray.sortingDisguisedStringsThrowsClassCastException(TestToArray.java:51)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) <9 internal lines>
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) <30 internal lines>
> at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source) <7 internal lines>
> at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
> at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)

Note that: 1. the failed cast is from `[Ljava.lang.Object` to `[Ljava.lang.Number` rather than from `java.lang.Object` to `java.lang.Number` as we would expect it to be for a failed cast inside the `compare` method and 2. the `ClassCastException` is thrown from inside the `TestToArray` class and *not* from the `Arrays` class.

The test `sortingDisguisedStringsThrowsClassCastExceptionAtArrayAssignment` shows that simply assigning the array of `String[]` to an array of `Number[]` throws that same `ClassCastException`.

The last test, `sortingNonComparableWithNullComparatorThrowsClassCastException` does in fact throw the expected `ClassCastException` and this is the only case where I was able to get the `sort` method itself to throw this exception. Printing the stacktrace to std_out yields the following (reduced for brevity):

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Double cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.Double and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
> at java.base/java.lang.Integer.compareTo(Integer.java:72)
> at java.base/java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:320)
> at java.base/java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:188)
> at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1041)
> at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1228)
> at org.example.basics.generics.arrays.TestToArray.lambda$sortingNonComparableWithNullComparatorThrowsClassCastException$5(TestToArray.java:67) <30 internal lines>
> at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source) <7 internal lines>
> at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
> at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)

Note that in this case the failed cast is from java.lang.Double to java.lang.Integer and the exception is actually thrown from the `Arrays` class.

Is the only case where `Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)` can throw `ClassCastException` the case where the value `null` is passed for the comparator `c`?

Context: I'm hoping to find out what kind of mistakes I need to make in order for the type system to no longer be able to function as a safeguard against `ClassCastException` for `sort`. So far it seems that the compiler will at the very least issue an "unchecked" warning which is reassuring. Is there any way to get a `ClassCastException` from `sort` without the compiler issuing "unchecked" warnings (and without passing `null` in place of `c`)?

Comment: Really just throwing several things at the wall in an attempt to get `sort` to throw the `ClassCastException` the javadoc warns of.
Clearly this was not one that worked, as execution doesn't even enter `sort` as you point out.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for, thanks!

Comment: It's possible with a contrived Comparator such as `(a, b) -> { throw new ClassCastException("Fake!"); }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is super simple to trigger if you have raw types (whether accidental or not):

```
class FawltyComparators {
    @Test
    void test() {
        final Comparator numberComparer = new NumberComparator();
        final Object[] array = { 1, 2, "3", "4" };
        Arrays.sort(array, numberComparer);
    }

    private static final class NumberComparator implements Comparator<Number> {
        @Override
        public int compare(final Number o1, final Number o2) {
            return 0; // doesn't matter
        }
    }
}
```

But this will still give you compiler warnings:

```
FawltyCompators.java:17: warning: [unchecked] unchecked method invocation: method sort in class Arrays is applied to given types
        Arrays.sort(array, numberComparer);
                   ^
  required: T[],Comparator<? super T>
  found:    Object[],Comparator
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>sort(T[],Comparator<? super T>)
FawltyCompators.java:17: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
        Arrays.sort(array, numberComparer);
                           ^
  required: Comparator<? super T>
  found:    Comparator
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>sort(T[],Comparator<? super T>)
```

Comment: But then this either won't compile or gives  warnings about using raw types in a comparator and an unchecked warning for `Arrays.sort();`

Comment: @WJS it compiles. I have extended the answer to show the compiler warnings

Comment: Yeah, your're correct .  I was trying something else an made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you pay attention to the definition of `mutually comparable`, it is that "[The Comparator] must not throw a ClassCastException". None of your tests actually violate that rule.

```
class ArraysTest {
    @Test
    public void sortingWithBadComparitor() {
        Number[] numbers = new Number[] { 4.0, 2, 3.0f };
        Throwable e = Assertions.assertThrows(ClassCastException.class, () -> {
            Arrays.sort(numbers, (o1, o2) -> {
                throw new ClassCastException();
            });
        });
        
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    static final Comparator<Number> compareAsWholeNumberWithBug = new Comparator<Number>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(java.lang.Number o1, java.lang.Number o2) {
            if (o1 instanceof Integer) { // Bug: assumes that if o1 is an integer, so is o2
                return ((Integer) o1).intValue() - ((Integer) o2).intValue();
            }
            
            return Long.compare(o1.longValue(), o2.longValue());
        }
    };
    
    @Test
    public void sortingWithBuggyComparitor() {
        Throwable e = Assertions.assertThrows(ClassCastException.class, () -> {
            Arrays.sort(new Number[] { 4.0, 2, 3.0f }, compareAsWholeNumberWithBug);
        });
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You might object because the sort method is not actually throwing a new `ClassCastException`, but that is true in plenty of other places in the Java documentation. The `@throws` tag is frequently used for Exceptions thrown by calls in the implementation that the method does not catch.

Comment: This is a good point. I hadn't considered the `Comparator` to throw a `ClassCastException` due to a bug in its own code.
I do object slightly because I suspect that wasn't the reason this part of the documentation was added. `c.compare` might throw any old exception (say, `NullpointerException`, or even `IndexOutOfBoundsException`) but it's meaningless to document this possibility in the `Arrays` class. Isn't the same true for `ClassCastException`?

Comment: I presume the "bug" you're talking about here is home grown and not in any API code.